# JS: Unit testing a class function without making the actual API call?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, testing, sinon

I have a simple class `Foo` in Typescript.  What is the best way to unit test this without actually making the API call?

I can't think of anything to spy or stub since I don't want it actually calling my real endpoint. Are there still tests to write for it?

```
class Foo {
    private _names: Array;

    constructor(private _accessToken: string, private _environment: string) {}


   async getInclusiveData(name: String) {
     
        const config = {
            method: "post",
            headers: HEADER_INFO
        };

        const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/v1/variations/match`, config);
        
        const { results } = (await response.json()) as any;

        this._names = results;

        return this._names;
}
```

All I ended up doing was:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    const fakeToken = "12345";
    const env = "prod";

    foo = new Foo(fakeToken, env);

    getInclusiveDataSpy = sinon.spy(foo, "getInclusiveData");
});
```

but in order to get that spy to run, I'd have to invoke: `foo.getInclusiveData()` so it doesn't feel like I'm really testing anything

Comment: If all you want to test is that the method calls `fetch` with the right arguments, then you need to give it a mocked `fetch` function. If the method does more than just an HTTP call and that's the part you want to test, then maybe you need an extra level of abstraction so you can test the class while mocking the part that actually does the HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing `getInclusiveData` method, so you should not stub and spy on it. This method uses `fetch` to make an HTTP request to the remote API server.
For unit testing, we want our test cases can be run isolated and don't do any real I/O operation. So we can stub or mock these I/O and side effect operations. We will stub `fetch` function in your case.

E.g.

`foo.ts`:

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

export class Foo {
  private _names: any[] = [];

  constructor(private _accessToken: string, private _environment: string) {}

  async getInclusiveData() {
    const config = { method: 'post', headers: {} };
    const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/v1/variations/match`, config);
    const { results } = (await response.json()) as any;
    this._names = results;
    return this._names;
  }
}
```

`foo.test.ts`:

```
import { Foo } from './foo';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('72721041', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const fakeToken = '12345';
    const env = 'prod';
    const foo = new Foo(fakeToken, env);
    const response = {
      json: sinon.stub().resolves({ results: ['a', 'b'] }),
    };
    (global as any).fetch = sinon.stub().resolves(response);
    const actual = await foo.getInclusiveData();
    sinon.assert.match(actual, ['a', 'b']);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  72721041
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (6ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 foo.ts   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```